# Is it possible to build android application other than java and c/cpp?

Tags: java, android, node.js, react-native

I am new to android and I have covered the basics in java for backend and xml for frontend. What I would like to know is: is it possible to develop an android application completely using react and node? Also, how would it be implemented? If there are some tutorials available for this that anyone could recommend, that would be helpful. I want to know if android backend can be built in any language other than java, c/cpp.

Comment: It is possible to create hybrid app using js techonolies, which means you only need to load web app in WebVIew which is basically browser in android.

Answer (score 1):

If you read  [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/](http://react%20native%20page) you will know a bit more of how it works, but to build a native app, you need to use a framework that generates native code, or write in a language that the device can compile, like the ones you sad before. React Native generates native code.